# React-Bootstrap Modal Accessibility Warnings from React-A11y

Tags: wai-aria, react-bootstrap

React-A11y yells at my Modal for 'tabIndex' and 'role'. My Modal looks like this:

```
    <Modal
        aria-label="..."
        tabIndex={-1}
        role="Dialog"
        show={this.state.showInfo}
        onHide={this.closeInfo.bind(this)} >
        <Modal.Header tabIndex={9} role="Dialog" closeButton>
            <Modal.Title tabIndex={-1} role="Dialog">...</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body tabIndex={-1} role="Dialog">
            ...
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
```

As you can see from above, I do have tabIndex and role in every Element, but when I checkout React plugin I found out that A11y is yelling at the child of Modal that I can't access:

[image: React plugin showing the child Modal]

I am not allowed to use other modified Modals like React-Accessible-Modal. So is there any ways for me to go around to get rid of this warning? Thanks

Comment: Tabindex is not a good practice, negative tabindex escape the elements. Sometimes the positive tabindex affects the natural order in the elemens is better to organice the elements in the order that you want and avoid this property.

Answer (score 0):

Top element is correct. Immediate child `div` should have `role="document"` and NO `tabIndex`.  In fact only your root element (the dialog box) should have `tabIndex="-1"`.  All other roles should be removed.

Tabindex affects tabbing order.  If you set it 0, then that element will be able to receive focus via tabbing.  I would avoid this if possible.  Browsers allow focus on interactive elements.  Consider wrapping elements you want to receive focus in an anchor or the like.

Tabindex as a positive is a no no.  Totally messes up tabbing order.

Tabindex -1 is actually fine, but ONLY if that element is to receive focus programmatically via js

```
[Element].focus();
```

So your dialog should programmatically receive focus and just allow a natural tabbing order for the rest.

Note: trap focus in the modal until the user closes the modal. Then return focus to the modal trigger(anchor or button, I prefer anchor)

Comment: How do you trap focus in the modal? I'm having a similar problem where my React modal content isn't being read by the Screen Reader (JAWS)

Comment: read this https://www.marcozehe.de/2015/02/05/advanced-aria-tip-2-accessible-modal-dialogs/